# Book revision page showing access denied if no revision present

Tags: 7, nodes

I've edited the content type *Book* to "create a new revision" whenever user publishes the page (while creation and editing the page).
[image: snap]

I have created a custom menu *Book revisions*, with path `node/[node:nid]/revisions` using [menu token](http://drupal.org/project/menu_token) module. It renders `http://site-url/4/revisions` with `4` as the node id of current node.
I am using [Nice menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) module to create the menu block and have placed it on every book page so that user can see the revisions whenever he is on the book page.

When I first create a page, and click on this menu, it gives me Access denied page (I'm logged in as user1). But, the moment I edit the page and save it, it works as expected - showing the different revisions.
**Requirement:** I want to display "No revisions" instead of "Access denied" to users. How can this be done?
I'm also open to suggestions to hide the menu for the first time, and again show it as soon as a revision of the node is created.

**Edit:** I find that if a node is not revised (edited), `node_revision` table has only one `vid` for the `nid` of node; and if the node is revised the table contain one `vid` per revision.
Using this information and a database query, I think it would be possible to find out whether a node has revision. Something like

```
$result = db_query('SELECT n.nid from {node_revision} n WHERE n.nid LIKE :uid',array(':uid' => arg(1)));    
$temp_var = 0;
foreach ($result as $result_item) {
  $temp_var++;
}
//If revisions are present $temp_var>1
//Only one version present if $temp_var == 1
if($temp_var == 1) {
  //menu unset code goes here...
}
```

I am just not sure in which *hook* should I implement this.

**EDIT:** I'm using [Diff module](http://drupal.org/project/diff) to enable the users to view the differences in two revisions.

Comment: Could you use a view to generate the "menu"? If you're using panels, you can sniff out revision status to determine whether or not to show the menu.

Comment: I'm using nice menus module to generate the menu. Please see the edit.

Comment: A shorter check for revision
function has_revisions($nid) {
$result = db_query("SELECT COUNT(vid) FROM {node_revision} WHERE nid = :nid", array(':nid' => $nid));
return ($result->fetchField() > 1);
}

Define a custom menu callback that accepts a nid. Redirect or http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_access_denied/7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood this right, you have a (Nice) menu on node pages, and you've added the `node/[node:nid]/revisions` item to that menu. You're not actually listing revisions, just making a link to the revisions page, right?

If so, the problem is that the access callback for that menu item is hardcoded to return access denied if a node doesn't have revisions. Actually looks like this is [being fixed](http://drupal.org/node/808730) for D8. Normally the tab wouldn't show, but it is in your case because you're creating the menu item in a different way, and the access is not checked when the link is printed. The solutions I can think of:

1. Replace the page with a view listing node revisions. Easy, but I don't know if you can replicate all the core revisions page functionality.
2. Create a wrapper menu item around the core revisions page using `hook_menu()`. Call it something else, like `node/%node/revs`. In the callback for that menu item, check if the node has revisions. If so, return the output of `node_revision_overview($nid)`, the core function that generates that page. Otherwise, return 'No revisions'
3. Use `hook_menu_alter()` to take the existing revisions menu item (`node/%node/revisions`) and move it to your menu. Take a look at the definition of the menu item in node.module line 2043. You'll need to change it to not be a `LOCAL_TASK` and then use the [menu_name](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) property to tell it to get into your custom menu. I'm pretty sure this can work.

Comment: 1+ for hook_menu_alter and the answer in general.

Comment: thank you for the response. I'm testing the solution. Views has filters for revisions, but I'm using [Diff module](http://www.drupal.org/project/diff) to find the difference in the revisions. I'm not sure how if the functionality of the module could be accommodated into a view.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a module that contextually defines which error page is shown to the user. Basically, you could create a node with content indicating there are no revisions to the book you are viewing and display that 403 page instead of the default 403 page through contexts (probably defined by URL structure including [node:nid]/revisions).

Try [Context Error](http://drupal.org/project/context_error) or perhaps [CustomError](http://drupal.org/project/customerror).

Comment: I'll look at both of the options in the morning, and will let you know. thank you..